# optimized static padding for strassen's odd matrices

Tags: c, algorithm, strassen

I'm trying to address the issue of odd matrices for strassen's algorithm. My implementation truncates the recursion at a certain point, call it Q, and switches over to the standard implementation. Therefore in doing static padding, I don't actually need to pad up to the next power of 2. I just need to pad up to the least m*2^k greater than the input matrix dimension such that m < Q.

I'm having some trouble implementing this - mainly because I'm not sure what would be most efficient. Do I need to loop through all possible m values, or do I increment from each given input, testing if they fulfill the criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Padding up to m * 2^k should perform much better than padding up to next power of 2.

I think you should pad up to value calculated by this function:

```
int get_best_pud_up_value(int actual_size, int Q) {
    int cnt = 0;
    int n = actual_size;
    while(n > Q) {
        cnt++;
        n /= 2;
    }

    // result should be smallest value such that:
    // result >= actual_size AND
    // result % (1<<cnt) == 0

    if (actual_size % (1<<cnt) == 0) {
        return actual_size;
    } else {
        return actual_size + (1<<cnt) - actual_size % (1<<cnt);
    }
}
```

Comment: For actual_size = 258, Q = 17, this is returning 256, which I think is incorrect. I would want it to pad to 272. The issue is when you get an odd number by dividing by 2, but before you've reached the threshold.

Comment: You are correct. My previous solution was wrong. I have corrected it. Now for actual_size = 258 and Q=17 returning value is 272 :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the above as inspiration, I believe to have found a more concise algorithm for finding the minimum padding

It works by repeatedly making the number divisible by 2 until it is below the threshold, then multiplying it by 2**counter to get the size the matrix must be padded to, in order to be repeatedly divisible by two until it is less than the threshold

```
unsigned int minPad(unsigned int inSize, unsigned int threshold) {
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    while (inSize > threshold) {
        inSize++;
        inSize >>= 1;
        counter ++;
    }
    return inSize << counter;
}
```

Comment: Note the inSIze++ could be replaced with if (inSize % 2) inSize++; however since an even number plus 1 integer division / 2 is equal to itself it's harmless to always add one